Scientifically plausible portal technology
In the book I'm writing, a shady company called Black Holes, Inc. is trying to build a transuniversal, or at least intergalactic, portal. I've tried to do a bunch of research about quark matter, hadron particles and fermion matter, wormholes, quark matter, etc, but it just breaks my brain and I can't translate it into how they could use those things to construct a functioning portal. I imagine the in-portal is located on earth, but I don't know how they would dictate where the out-portal is, or is they could. Like, do they just create a black hole/wormhole and the white hole on the other end just spawns somewhere in space? Normally I wouldn't go into this much detail, but Black Holes kidnaps a character and explains all of their science-y stuff to him, so I need to know exactly what they're doing. Basically what I'm asking is what method would they use to create the portal, how exactly would they apply the different elements and particles and matter related to it to make the portal, what it would look like, how the out-portal destination works, etc. Also this would not be humans just stepping into it, it would be like Big Hero 6 style with the vehicle going into it. This is probably super confusing and I can offer any extra clarification/detail upon request. Thank you!!

So you are asking us to explain something that works only in your mind?

Although black holes have been observed, we aren't actually certain of how they work under the hood. Worm holes are entirely theoretical, and are likely the kind of mathematical fantasy that occurs when cosmologists get a little loose with their definition of a dimension. That makes them effectively "magic," and therefore not something that anyone could speak authoritatively on.

This question is similar to: How could I make a portal to parallel universes as scientifically realistic as possible?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, please note that you might be falling into the "As Realistic As Possible" trap. It's a fad that's been going on since the movie Intergalactic and the TV series The Expanse. Those shows aren't as scientifically realistic as one might think, but it's spurned this desire for young authors to write at technical levels that would challenge PhD candidates. Are you sure you need to explain your portals to that level of detail? Most authors haven't. Most (like Stargate) present a device that uses "wormholes" to create the portal... then move on with the story they really want to tell.

Clearly the plot is not dependent on the explanation behind how the portal works (just what it does), so why as a writer are you feeling the need to describe in details the technobabble explanation to the character?  Given real world physics it will a) be nonsense, b) be something you won't understand and c) be something most readers won't understand (the few exceptions will recognise it as nonsense).  So, write it differently - either "over the next few hours they described the advanced maths of portal generation" or they said "it's proprietary information".

Note that it takes an infinite amount of coordinate time to fall into a black hole, since time dilation asymptotically goes to infinity at the horizon (the important part). Traveling at any speed, a stationary observer will see you eventually come to a near-stop right above the horizon.

For all of you who are asking why Josephine feels the need to explore this rabbit hole, I'd just like to point out, perhaps as a reminder, that this forum is about worldbuilding. So many of you are just so eager to answer questions about orbital mechanics and weapon systems and flying humanoids and so forth. What's wrong with explaining a bespoke transgalactic portal system? First, she is clearly trying to wrap her brain around some very difficult physics. So, this is a real world query with fictional world application. She didn't specify, but this story may or may not be set within (cont)

(cont) the real universe. Clearly, it's a SF universe! I don't like real world queries here, but I do favour them when there is a clear fictional context. Second, I don't know if Josephine is doing this or not, but many worldbuilder authors actually do jump down all the rabbit holes of their worlds to discover everything they can.  Third, I'd say that she is actually a rather forward thinking author! The simple fact of the matter is that SF & F stories often spark interest in the ancillary works that chronical the world itself. People that read like to know how things work, and (cont)

(cont) people like to read and study about these other worlds their favourite stories are set in. Hence, we can fill a pretty decent book shelf with all the books that focus on Middle Earth as a place --- maps, Middle Earth guides, the History of Middle Earth, Children of Hurin and all the recently released stories, an atlas or two of ME, the author's letters. For the Star Trek fans, we've got technical manuals, blueprints, ever improved encyclopedias, books in Klingon, and the like. Same goes for Star (cont)

(cont) Wars, Harry Potter, Discworld, Pern and who knows how many others! Lastly, she could just be doing this, ultimately, for the intellectual challenge of trying to understand something interesting!

@JosephineMaldonado: Hi! Your question got closed recently. You got much feedback already. I would like to know if you feel you got everything you need or do you want to try to improve the question and give it another go?

Wormholes Primer from a (pseudo-)scientific standpoint.
Broadly speaking you have two options:

Natural way: Has something to do with "jumping into an existing black hole"
Technical way: Has something to do with a machine that creates something like a black hole to jump in.

Now, black holes are tricky as you already know, I assume. Because (a) gravity and (b) until now no one entered a black hole, let alone have any idea what really would happen. The range goes from: Anything is disintegrated into Hawking radiation to You can enter the black hole and even touch the singularity if you like, because inside the black hole at some point deep enough in, gravity is "normal" or "consistent" again.
One problem everybody agrees upon is: If you entered a black hole, you cannot come back. And another trope many agree upon is: If there is a white hole on the other side, you can leave through that hole into a different universe. And as a (logical?) consequence it might be possible that: If this universe has a blackhole as well and the whitehole ends in the previous universe, you might have a way to come back home again.
At this point you as an author are fully submersed in the Sci-Fi world. There is nothing right or wrong here. Just what you deem to be cool and fitting.
Some hints can be given:

Commercial Use: If portal travelling is somewhat common and "natural" black holes are used, you might consider having something like a space station close to it from where the "passengers" embark and arrive again (Think "Deep Space 9" here, if you like or "Babylon 5", etc.)

Protection: Opening portals through black holes are things of extremely high energy levels. Speaking of levels that probably are not possible to achieve on earth if all the sun's output was converted into pure energy (but I didn't run any numbers). If something goes wrong, you probably gonna die. Unless there is some technology that helps with that. Energy force fields, slipstream technology etc. you need to make something up.

Invention: There was probably some point where a brilliant mind had the theory developed of how it can be practically possible to create, open, hold open, enter, travel through, and exit safely at a controlled destination (space and also time, maybe). Sounds crazily impossible. So, if you like, add alien technology of sorts, this makes things plausible easily. Or make plausible why there is a "Thousand-stein" instead of just a "One-stein" in your world (Einstein translated literally, where "Ein=One" and "stein=stone").

Energy: If you go with artificially created black holes, you need to solve the problem of energy consumption to create a black hole. This is something like a very huge and efficient Fusion Generator, like a Tokamak but in "good and working at 100%".

Company: The company might want to be staying earth bound and also have their "monopoly" over the technology secured. This can have all sorts of corporate mischief going on as a consequence. Maybe they even have funded R&D massively as the initial theories were brought to light and were to first to succeed. Then it is up to you, if they are a kind of "travel service provider on commercial scale" or just using the portal for internal, "black-ops"-missions etc.

Control Beacon / Setup a wormhole: To initiate the connection between two spots in the galaxy you probably need one mission that reaches the destination of the the portal by conventional/different means (Makes travelling close to c necessary or maybe even FTL).
The core idea is: There has to be some kind of beacon, a very high amount of mass or a kind of technology manipulating gravity, in fact another black hole, which needs to be altered in a way that the ends of those gravity funnels of two black holes connect to each other. This is slightly different from a back-white-hole bridge, but could still be plausible.
Other explanations draw from "naturally existing wormholes" that might be discovered and the network being expanded from there. Those might have been created by (long extinct) alien life forms. These are the classic tropes, but you might find better/different ones.


If you want to have a primer on black/white holes, I suggest watching this Veritasium video about Eintein's Theory with the topics of Einstein-Rosen-Bridges (espeically section "Traversable Wormholes" has also a picture) and Space-Time-Diagrams (Future light cone / Past light cone; also see Minkowsky Space).
As outlined, the theory is really just a theory. We never ever even observed a whitehole let alone a wormhole. Also think about it as "a blackhole might have an exit in a whitehole, but this is no rule without exceptions".
It is a theoretical/mathematical construct only and the wet dream of any Sci-Fi enthusiast to become true. Give them (us) something to dream!
